# Reinstall Shopify App Error: "The Page is not Avalaible

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am developing the shopify app according to the tutorial presented on the page (QR create code), however when I am doing tests, when I uninstall it and try to reinstall it I get the following message:

There is no page at this address

Please check the URL and try again, or use the search bar to find what you need. (Attached in the photo)

[Photo 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1eEF.png)

If you can help me, thank you very much, I feel that it is as if the authentication failed or I had already used the token, the truth is that I do not know about the subject

My project is in node, react

```
"@shopify/app": "3.3.3",
"@shopify/cli": "3.3.3"
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late, Yes is a bug of Shopify, when i reinstall all then i have no problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shopify_app bug
You need to delete the previous installation Shop from the database then try the install again and it will work.

If you have only one shop in the database quick solution will be the rails console

```
rails c
Shop.first.destroy
```

To resolve it permanently you have to register and handle the app_uninstalled webhook however it will not work 100% of the time due to delay. When the user removes the app the Shopify server trigger webhook with delay (2 seconds to 10 minutes)

Comment: I will try what you told me and let you know Thanks!

Comment: can you point the documentation to use shop.first.destroy? how do you access to those properties?

Comment: @pedrommuller run commands in the rails console https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-console

Answer (score 0):

For those of you in PHP do these steps.

If you have the Migrations folder in your project. You can find it on this path.
`web/database/migrations`.

delete the `db.sqlite` file from your storage folder. `web/storage`.

and then type this command in your terminal.

`php artisan migrate`